# Rank of a linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is equal to $m$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Take a linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $n>m$. Is the rank of $f$ always equal to $m$?

Since the image of $f$ contains $\{f(a) |  a \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$, the image will contain $m$-tuples, of which the standard basis is $\{(1,0,\cdots,0),(0,1,\cdots,0),\cdots,(0,0,\cdots,1)\}$ which has dimension $m$. So the $rank(f)=m$?

I haven't come across this result before, is that right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, why would the standard basis be a subset of the image?

For example, take $f=0$ the zero operator. It is obviously linear, but the rank is zero since $im(f)=\{f(a)|\:a\in\mathbb R^n\}=\{0\}$ is zero dimentional.

Comment: That makes sense thank you. Can I then say that the $rank(f)\leq m$?

Comment: Yes, since $im(f)\subset \mathbb R^m$ and every subspace has dimension which is $\leq$ the dimension of the big space - m.

Comment: $\operatorname{rank} f=m$ means $f$ is surjective.